# Does KafkaConsumer#pause effect the current call to poll?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If I set my own rebalance listener, and inside of `onPartitionsAssigned`, call `consumer.pause(partitions)`, will the current call to `poll`, from within which the rebalance listener was called, return any records?

Where in the docs would I have looked to find this answer for myself?

Edit:

I did see this in the docs -

> Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using resume(Collection). Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used.

But I don't feel that this definitively states whether the call to `poll` currently in progress will return data for partitions that I pause within the rebalance callback called inside of `poll`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I get you question. But from the specification is it clean the `pause()` affect *future* calls to poll.

> Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using resume(Collection). Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used.

https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)

Comment: I did see " Future calls to poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed "  in the docs.  My question is whether "future calls to poll" includes the call to poll that is currently in progress (the rebalance callback is called from within poll, and you can pause from within the callback).    A normal understanding of the english language might suggest "no", but it seems to me that "yes"  would constitute better API design, so I wonder whether that is the meaning that the docs intended to convey here.